# ¿Cómo lograr que una caja contenedora ocupe cierto porcentaje del alto de la pantalla?

Tags: html, css

Estoy empezando con el diseño web (con html, css, etc). Mi problema es que tengo una barra lateral que solo ocupa el espacio para que entren los elementos, pero como se ve en la imagen yo quiero que llegue hasta abajo. Ya probé con height: 100% pero no funciona. ¿Alguno tiene idea de como resolverlo?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿y tu HTML? Será que no has intentado nada?

Comment: algo de codigo amigo, html, css.. sin el, no es mucho lo que puede hacer, mas que suponer lo que estas tratando de hacer. saludos

Comment: Perdón por la falta de código. Ya me lo solucionaron gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quieres usar porcentajes en vez de `vh` o `vw`, puedes usar el siguiente código:

**HTML**:

```
<div class="o-container">Container</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
body, html { height: 100%; }
.o-container { height: 100%; background-color: #000000; }
```

Answer (score 0):

en CSS o style aplica `height: 100vh;` de la dicha etiqueta

`vh` es view height y `vw` view width

Comment: aquí un buen recurso para lo responsivo: https://gist.github.com/gokulkrishh/242e68d1ee94ad05f488